# Can I implement phone specific sizing with XAML in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML

```
<Grid x:Name="scoreFaveGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="5,0,0,0"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
```

I understand that with C# I can make the padding sizes etc change depending on if I am using iOS or Android.

Can I do the same with XAML and if so how is that done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `<OnPlatform>` tag in XAML. Here's how it would work for Padding in your sample above.

```
<Grid x:Name="scoreFaveGrid" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid.Padding>
        <OnPlaform x:TypeArguments="x:Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="15,0,15,0" />
            <On Platform="Android" Value="5,0,5,0"/>
        </OnPlaform>
    </Grid.Padding>
</Grid>
```